# How to select more than one buffer for an Icicle Multibuffer search

Tags: icicles

1) launch: Search->Icicles->+Search Buffers
2) Input my regex
3) Iclcles presents the buffer *Completions* with my buffers listed.

How do I select more than one?

Thanks

Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, in [**Icicles**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) <kbd>C-RET</kbd> (aka <kbd>C-return</kbd>) is the candidate action key.  Wnenever you use a [multi-command](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Multi-Commands) , it acts on the current completion candidate, without exiting the minibuffer. (You can cycle to a candidate to make it current.)

Alternatively, you can just click a candidate in buffer `*Completions*` with <kbd>C-mouse-2</kbd>. Another alternative is to use the menus.  So even if for some reason you cannot use <kbd>C-RET</kbd> you can still choose multiple candidates (in this case, buffers), by clicking them.

If, however, you want to change the candidate action key from <kbd>C-RET</kbd> to something else, just customize user option [`icicle-candidate-action-keys`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Customization_and_General_Tips#toc22) -- it is the list of keys that act on the current candidate.

More generally, even when there is not a specific user option (such as `icicle-candidate-action-keys`) for customizing a particular key, you can always assign the key you want. For a top-level key, just define the key you want in `icicle-mode-map`.
For a minibuffer key, use function `add-hook` together with `minibuffer-setup-hook` and `minibuffer-exit-hook` to add and remove the key binding to/from the `current-local-map` (which will be the current minibuffer map).

See [customizing Icicles key bindings](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Customizing_Key_Bindings).

Answer (score 0):

**Found the answer.**
C-Enter selects, enter when done.
The problem is that C-Enter is bound to cua-set-rectangle-mark while CUA mode is active.
Icicles hangs when C-enter is typed in this context.
Therefore a binding conflict exists between Icicles candidate selection and CUA mode.
Something like a hook is needed for the binding during Icicles candidate selection.
Perhaps one exists already that I am not aware of?

Thanks
Mike

Answer (score 0):

Both *Icicle* mode and *CUA* mode are minor modes. Minor-mode key bindings take precedence, even over minibuffer bindings. So even though `cua-set-rectangle-mark` makes little sense in the minibuffer it is in effect there when you are in CUA mode.

The solution is to customize either **Icicles** or CUA mode to not have a key conflict here.  For CUA, I believe you can customize option `cua-rectangle-mark-key`.  For **Icicles** you can customize option [`icicle-candidate-action-keys`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Customizing_Key_Bindings#icicle-candidate-action-keys).  In general, **Icicles** key bindings are customizable -- see [Icicles - Customizing Key Bindings](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Customizing_Key_Bindings)